# pytorch, for the cross_entropy function, What if the input labels are all ignore_index?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, gradient-descent

for the nn.CrossEntropyLoss(),  What if the input labels are all ignore_index ? I got a 'nan' loss, how to fix it ? thanks!

detail of my code is following:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3SUbh.png)
notice that IGNORE_INDEX is -100
then, the loss_ent becomes 'nan', the input of func criterion() is following:
[criterion's input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvJ9S.png)

my python environment is following:

- Python:3.7.11
- torch:1.12.0+cu116
- GPU:NVIDIA A100 80G

thank for your attention, Please let me know if there is anything else I need to provide.

Comment: please upload your code. It is necessary to give you a clear answer.

Comment: thanks for your attention, my code have been uploaded. This problem has been bothering me for a long time, thank you very much！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be two possibilities.

1. This is the code to help understand the ignore index. If you set all inputs to ignore index, criterion makes nan as output because there is no value to compute.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

x = torch.randn(5, 10, requires_grad=True)
y = torch.ones(5).long() * (-100)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=-100)
loss = criterion(x, y)
print(loss)
```

```
tensor(nan, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward0>)
```

However, if there is even one value to calculate, the loss is calculated properly.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

x = torch.randn(5, 10, requires_grad=True)
y = torch.ones(5).long() * (-100)
y[0] = 1

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(ignore_index=-100)
loss = criterion(x, y)
print(loss)
```

```
tensor(1.2483, grad_fn=<NllLossBackward0>)
```

2. It seems the learning rate is too large that cause diverge.

As you can see in the figure below, if the learning rate is large, the gradient gradually increases and diverges.

How about reducing the learning rate of the parameters of the model with is_gold_ent as output?

Usually, when reducing the learning rate, reduce it by 1/3. For example 0.01, 0.003, 0.001,...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, as you can see from my code, my model is a multi-task model. I'm trying your suggestion to reduce the learning rate from 1e-5 to 3e-6. thanks again!

Comment: I still want to make sure it's not the 'all ignore_index label' cause the problem ? because When the label of a batch is not all ignore_index the loss is normal. so the title is <what if the input label are all ignore_index>.  it confuse me for a long time.

Comment: I was a little bit wrong. I added description for ignore index. Hope you understand well. Thanks!

Comment: thank you very much, problem solved ! I set the nan loss to zero. then the code can running normally. thank you again.